# UITableView contentOffset behaving oddly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a UIViewController which has multiple UIViews that enter from off the screen. Rather than initializing and designing all those UIViews in the UIViewController, I created separate nib files with corresponding .h/.m files which just get preloaded.

In one of the custom UIViews, I have a UITableView with a header UIView. I'm trying to have this header hidden under another component I have in the original UIViewController that this UIView will slide into. I initially worked this out using a sample project with `[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44) animated:NO];`, but that was just in a UITableViewController.

For some reason, this does not work for a subclassed UIView. I've tried setting the tableView's content offset in both `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` and `- (void)layoutSubviews` and I've been checking whether the offset was actually set in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` by

```
NSLog(@"tableView Content Offset: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.tableView.contentOffset));
```

but it just returns

`tableView Content Offset: {0, 0}`

The interesting thing is that if I set the contentOffset in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` it works! But I know I shouldn't be setting it there. Could someone explain to me where and how I should be implementing this when loading a UITableView from a custom nib which is only a subclassed UIView? I can post all the code if you think it'll help.

**Additional Info:**
Question: *how are you loading the view from the nib ? –  MAB*

```
UIView *newView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProfileCostTableViewController" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Try setting it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

Comment: ```viewWillLayoutSubviews``` doesn't get called when subclassing UIView. I'm trying trying to get this to work in a subclassed UIView, not a UIViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I subclassed `UITableView` to see when the contentOffset is being rest to {0,0}. it seems its a call in ios7 from the private method : `_adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary`. Since this method is not documented I don't see how to prevent it from changing the offset, so I think the workaround is to change the offset after a delay or in `- (int) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`.

Comment: I'll give the delay a try, but seems pretty hackish. Just very odd that the contentOffset gets reset to {0, 0}. Unfortunately though, setting the contentOffset does not work in ```tableView:numberOfRowsInSection``` either. It so far has only worked in ```tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:``` and ```tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:```

Comment: So, ```[self performSelector:@selector(setContentOffset) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0]``` actually works! And I can set it in ```initWithCoder``` where I originally wanted to. I'll mark this as correct, with the only caveat that for a split moment you can see the content I'm trying to hide that snaps into the correct offset when the method is called. Looks a little funky, but it's good enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding your view using `addSubview:` which triggers the methods: `- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview` I think if you put your code there it should work.

Comment: Tried it, but still doesn't work. Logging the tableView's contentOffset in ```tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:``` still outputs {0, 0}. For some reason it's getting reset to 0.

Comment: how are you loading the view from the nib ?